# CSS only framework that utilizes clever pseudo classes for actions?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Is there any css only framework that utilizes things like :target pseudoclass for user actions, like opening a modal, or switching tabs?

Here's a demo that does this : http://demo.bitsofco.de/the-target-trick/modal.html#modal-container

I got so excited when I first saw this demo, but couldn't find any framework that utilizes it to the fullest.

Also what are other clever things you can do with pseudoclasses to ditch javascript from the front-end styling?

Comment: Sometimes you just gotta embrace javascript

Comment: @soulshined sometimes you reach a point as a developer where you must take a minimalist journey ;)

Comment: touche @mojimi its probably not made yet because its probably not fun to make and couldn't satisfy all the user related events, like keydown doubleclick etc

Comment: Using tons of inputs and labels to reproduce some click events, rather than simply use some JavaScript functions doesn't sound like "minimalist" for me...

Comment: Don’t be to hell-bent on replacing all front-end JavaScript with pure CSS “solutions” in the first place - the latter often have serious usability issues, that JavaScript can deal with much better (for example by setting/toggling ARIA attributes appropriately, etc.)